# Test a view function with a HTTP404 exception

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to test this view to ensure that it returns a HTTP404 if the RedirectUrl model class does not exist and redirect to the destination_url if it does. Also it should store the url.
Just for context, the app receives a url like so

```
www.xyz.com/redirect/1?whatsappid=12345
```

Does a meta refresh to

```
www.xyz.com/confirmredirect/1?whatsappid=12345
```

And finally passes the query parameter to another site

```
https://test_check.co.za/?whatsappid=12345
```

In the admin panel you see how many links were created and a count fo how many times the url was clicked.

```
#Views.py
def clickActivity(request: HttpRequest, pk: int, whatsappid: int) -> HttpResponse:
    try:
        redirect_url = RedirectUrl.objects.get(id=pk)
    except RedirectUrl.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No RedirectUrl matches the given query.")
    store_url_entry = RedirectUrlsEntry(url=redirect_url)
    store_url_entry.save()
    destination_url = f"{redirect_url.test_check_url}" f"/?whatsappid={whatsappid}"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(destination_url)
```

```
#models.py
class RedirectUrl(models.Model):

    url = models.URLField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default="https://hub.momconnect.za/confirmredirect",
    )
    content = models.TextField(
        default="This entry has no copy",
        help_text="The content of the mesage that this link was sent in",
    )
    symptom_check_url = models.URLField(
        max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default="http://symptomcheck.co.za"
    )
    parameter = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def my_counter(self):
        total_number = RedirectUrlsEntry.objects.filter(url=self.id).count()
        return total_number

    def __str__(self):
        if self.url:
            return (
                f"{self.parameter}: {self.url}/{self.id} \n"
                f"| Clicked {self.my_counter()} times | Content: {self.content}"
            )

class RedirectUrlsEntry(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(
        RedirectUrl, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.url:
            return (
                f"{self.url.url} with ID {self.url.id} \n"
                f"was visited at {self.time_stamp}"
            )
```

```
#Urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "confirmredirect/<int:pk>/<int:whatsappid>",
        views.clickActivity,
        name="ada_hook_redirect",
    ),
    path("redirect/<int:pk>", views.default_page, name="ada_hook"),
]
```

I was able to test that the right templates are used but I'm struggling with this test. I'm a Django newbie. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to write a test function

In which case you can create something like:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
  
    def test_redirecting_url(self):
        # Use a test client
        client = Client()
        # tell it to go to the url
        r = client.get(reverse('ada_hook', args=[pk]))
        # assert that it redirected correctly
        self.AssertRedirects(r, expected_url)
        # if checking the status 
        assert r.status_code == 404
```

Reading more into what I've put here will help massively with testing